Manage Nested Reducer States and Actions in React with TypeScript
I'm working on a React application with TypeScript, and I'm using useReducer to manage a complex state structure. My state has nested objects, and I'm struggling to type the state and actions correctly. Here's a simplified version of my setup:


type User = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
};

type Settings = {
  theme: 'light' | 'dark';
  notificationsEnabled: boolean;
};

type State = {
  user: User | null;
  settings: Settings;
};

type Action =
  | { type: 'setUser'; payload: User }
  | { type: 'clearUser' }
  | { type: 'updateTheme'; payload: 'light' | 'dark' }
  | { type: 'toggleNotifications' };

const initialState: State = {
  user: null,
  settings: {
    theme: 'light',
    notificationsEnabled: true,
  },
};

function reducer(state: State, action: Action): State {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'setUser':
      return { ...state, user: action.payload };
    case 'clearUser':
      return { ...state, user: null };
    case 'updateTheme':
      return { ...state, settings: { ...state.settings, theme: action.payload } };
    case 'toggleNotifications':
      return {
        ...state,
        settings: { ...state.settings, notificationsEnabled: !state.settings.notificationsEnabled },
      };
    default:
      throw new Error('Unknown action type');
  }
}

const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>User: {state.user ? state.user.name : 'No user logged in'}</p>
      <p>Theme: {state.settings.theme}</p>
      <p>Notifications: {state.settings.notificationsEnabled ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled'}</p>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'clearUser' })}>Clear User</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'updateTheme', payload: 'dark' })}>Set Dark Theme</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'toggleNotifications' })}>Toggle Notifications</button>
    </div>
  );
};




`

While this approach works, I'm having trouble with typing nested state, extending actions and of course error handling.
What are the best practices for typing nested states and actions in a React application using TypeScript? Are there patterns or utilities that can help manage complex reducers effectively?
